# Sails.js - issues when trying to display model data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have no problem retrieving all my models from the database and displaying them on page using this code:

```
index: function(req, res) {
    Applicant.find(function(err, applicants) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.view({
                apps: applicants
            });
        }
    });
}
```

But, if I try to pull just one model and display it, my browser gets stuck on loading. This is the code that I use for pulling just one model:

```
display: function(req, res) {
    Applicant.find().where({id: 2}).done(function(err, appl) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('HAI');
        }else{
            res.view({
                applicant: appl
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely, your browser is stuck because an error happens when you're trying to find an Applicant, and your code doesn't return any response in this case. So browser waits for response forever. 
Please try something like this

```
if (err) {
    console.log('HAI');
    return res.send(err, 500);
}
```

P.S. By the way, as of Sails v0.9, `find()` method will alwals return an array, even if only one record is found. If you want to find just one record by id, and expect single object in your view, you can use `findOne()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I've checked the framework's documentation (Migrating section) and I've read that the findOne method is deprecated

Comment: btw, as I am at the beginning of the Sails.js journey, would you happen to know any extra resources useful for learning? Apart from the documentation. Thank you!

Comment: The cite from mirgation guide: _One of the major changes that will effect your codebase are the changes away from `findAll`. We have adopted a MongoDB-like syntax starting in 0.9 and have replaced the methods with `findOne` and `find`._

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any extra resources related to Sails.js. It's very young project. If I misunderstand something, I look into source code of sails on github. Also, Stackoverflow is very good place to ask questions, as contributors of Sails often answer here.

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` returns an array. You may be expecting a single `applicant` object.

Using `appl[0]` would solve this. Please note that Sails' [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) ORM provides `.findOne()` for situations such as these. Here's [more info](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#query-methods) on `.findOne()`

```
display: function(req, res) {
    Applicant.find().where({id: 2}).done(function(err, appl) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('HAI');
        }else{
            res.view({
                applicant: appl[0]
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Or better yet...

```
display: function(req, res) {
    Applicant.findOne({id: 2}, function(err, appl) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('HAI');
        }else{
            res.view({
                applicant: appl
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are right, but this solution wouldn't solve the issue, described in the question. Browser will get stuck while waiting for response if any `err` occurs. So you should provide some response in `if (err)` case.

Comment: Great answer- be sure to always handle your errors!  That looks like:

display: function (req, res, next) {
    Applicant.findOne(2).exec(function (err, applicant) {
      // Use the default error handler in config/500.js
      if (err) return next(err);
      // Redirect to the home page if no applicants exist
      if (!applicant) return res.redirect('/');
      // Otherwise show the HTML page
      return res.view({applicant: applicant});
    });
}